# Integral of 1/x - base of logarithm

Tags: integration, logarithms

I see a proof in https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11965 (equation 3.36) that uses the following.

$\log x = \int_0^{\infty} ds \left(\frac{1}{1+s} - \frac{1}{s+x}\right)$.

This seems to hinge on $\int \frac{1}{x} = \log_2 x$ (the context is information theory), as opposed to $\log_e(x)$. Why is this true?

Comment: It isn't? It is true up to a multiplied constant, though, since $\log_2(x) = \ln(x)/\ln(2)$

Comment: What is the "this" in "this seems to hinge"?  The equation  $\log x = \int_0^{\infty} ds \left(\frac{1}{1+s} - \frac{1}{s+x}\right)$?  If so, why do you say it seems to hinge on $\int \frac 1x$[sic] $= \log_2x$? If something else in the article, what?

Comment: The notation in the pape is a little confusing because in the classical part entropy is measured in bits and $\log$ represents the base 2 logarithm, however part 3 deals with quantum entropy, and the definition by Von Newmann uses natural log - in fact the unit of entropy when using natural logarithm has a name, nat, nit, or nepit - see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat_(unit)

Comment: Ah @mlerma54, I think that's the error in my assumption then. I assumed quantum entropy also stayed in $log_2$. If you put your comment as an answer, I can accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation in the paper is a little confusing because in the classical part entropy is measured in bits and $\log$ represents the base 2 logarithm, however part 3 deals with quantum entropy, and the definition by Von Newmann uses natural log - in fact the unit of entropy when using natural logarithm has a name, nat, nit, or nepit - see e.g. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat_(unit)

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $a > 0$,
$$
\int_0^M \frac{1}{a+s}ds = \int_{a}^{M+a} \frac{1}{s} ds = \ln (M+a) - \ln a.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_0^M \left(\frac{1}{1+s} - \frac{1}{x+s}\right) ds =
\ln (M+1) - \ln 1 - (\ln (M+x) - \ln x).
$$
Therefore, by letting $M \to \infty$, we have
$$
\int_0^\infty  \left(\frac{1}{1+s} - \frac{1}{x+s}\right) ds = \ln x.
$$